# JPA exception handling

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, flush

I'm running certain process that inserts new elements in DB from a for loop. I'm using JPA (Eclipselink), and sometimes there's a problem with the transation status. This is the case:

1. One of the INSERTS doesn't work (Primary Key duplicated)
2. After that, all the inserts will fail (Exception Description: Transaction is currently active).

---

```
 for (Element l:e){
  try{
   //Should I add: if(!em.getTransaction().isActive())
   em.getTransaction().begin();
   em.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO...").executeUpdate();
   em.getTransaction().commit();
   }
  catch(Exception ep)
  {
   //right now I don't do anything here
  }
 }
```

I get that what is happening is that, since the commit in 1) didn't work, the transaction didn't finish, so the next em.getTransaction().begin() will find an already active transaction.

I have two ideas:

A) Before em.getTransaction().begin(), check if the transcation is active, and only if it is not, call begin(); otherwise, create query and commit.

B) Do something within the catch block. And here's my doubt... Should I call clear()? flush()? close()?

Which one looks better?
Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't you rollback transaction in response to the exception ?

Comment: `EntityManager.getTransaction()` returns an `EntityTransaction` object. Make sure you either `commit()` or `rollback()` on this transaction object.

Comment: You are using JPA but for native SQL inserts.. why not use Entities directly for the inserts?  You are also using 1 insert per transaction, is there a reason why you are not using a new EntityManager instance as well when you get an exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An exception thrown by `ElementManager.Query` does not rollback the active transaction. I see two options here:

1. Rollback the transaction by yourself within the catch clause with use of `em.getTransaction().rollback()`.
2. Instead of inserting data with query use the **preferred** way based on `EntityManager.persist` whose exceptions cause an automatic rollback (in your particular case this will lead to `javax.persistence.EntityExistsException`).